# php List users registered with same IP Addresses multiple times

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, pdo

I have stored members IP addresses in a field in database say `mem_ip` using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. I want to check users who have registered multiple accounts with same IP addresses to prevent spam (like preventing self referral creation). I created a page in my admin section where I began typing the query `SELECT mem_id, mem_uname, mem_ip FROM members WHERE....`  but then suddenly I realized that I do not exactly know how to proceed. How can I extract the list of those users who have registered multiple accounts with same IP address? Anybody who knows the trick please help me.

Table: members

```
mem_id    mem_uname    mem_email       mem_pass          mem_ip
1         demouser     user@gmail.com  bcryptHashCode    IPv4 / IPv6 format
```

Comment: set a UNIQUE constraint on an email address/username column. Why check for an IP address? it's not reliable.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner can you please elaborate?

Comment: Edit your question and show the schema of the table. Then we might be able to construct the needed query.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner how will that help?

Comment: when users sign up, they have an email/username, right? only let them login on that and not allow for duplicate email/usernames.

Comment: you could also assign it to a session and check if that session assigned to the user is already in use.

Comment: when they sign up they can simply use a new email and username each time. how can I detect whether they are spamming me? the best way, even if not reliable, will be to check if those multiple accounts were registered with same IP address or not.

Comment: you did not get my question right.. I understood now..

Comment: What about people who signup on the same IP many reasons that could happen, like a corporate network or people in the same house, uni dorm.. whilst still letting people multi account who use a VPN, IPs are not the way to go.. you more likely get cheaters using the same passwords, not IPs

Comment: See my answer below. But you should consider the possibility where a user uses a WiFi connection at a store or restaurant to register, and another user also uses that same location later to register and just happens to be given the same IP address.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Right you are; the OP didn't take my comment(s) into account neither.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone do not worry. I am going to give admins who purchase my PTC script to allow a maximum number of users per IP (say 5), exceeding which they won't be able to register :) Now this will depend upon the admin whether to set 1 or 100. My job is to provide them with this facility. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By joining to a sub-query that selects only those IP addresses that occur more than once, you can produce a list of users that have registered from a single ip address.

```
SELECT
    a.`mem_id`,
    a.`mem_uname`,
    a.`mem_ip`
FROM `members` a
JOIN (
    SELECT `mem_ip`,count(*) as `numrows` 
    FROM `members` 
    GROUP by `mem_ip`
    HAVING `numrows` > 1
) b
ON a.`mem_ip` = b.`mem_ip`
ORDER BY a.`mem_ip`,a.`mem_id`
```

Comment: how to echo the data if under while loop using extract($variable)? `<?php echo $a.mem_ip; ?>` ???? this way?

Comment: The PHP code to execute and output the results would be a whole different question. If you edit your question to show the PHP code you have now, I could give you a better answer. That said, it really should be a different question.